# Right click in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

How to use "right click" for seeing lists(new,cut,copy,paste etc) in Ubuntu 18 in Android Studio?[refer to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDYNH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to  `Settings->Devices->Mouse and Touchpad` and change `Primary Button` to `Left`

[image]